# Page is loaded without the css applied,and after a secnd it applies the CSS and renders it properly

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I run my project on localhost in IE8 and IE10, the page is first loaded without the CSS applied, and after a second it applies the CSS and renders it properly.However, when I run it in IE9 everything seems to work fine.

I wonder why is this happening. Can someone tell me what is wrong and how am I going to solve this matter? Thanks!

**EDIT**

html code

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$urls= explode("/",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
$location=$urls[2];
?>
<title>GASS Security || <?php echo $header_title;?></title>
<link href="css/gass_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elastislide.css" />
<script src="js/html5.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 /
 $('#menu img').hover(function() {
 var src = $(this).attr('src').substr(0, ($(this).attr('src').length - 4)) + 'Over.jpg';
$(this).attr('src', src)
    }, function() {
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace('Over', '');
 $(this).attr('src', src);
 })
  /
  $('.sumTitle').click(function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle('slow')
$(this).toggleClass('show')
 })

  });
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(window).load(function() {
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
  /*
 slideshowSpeed: 100,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
animationSpeed: 100,
  controlNav: true,
directionNav: true,
  pausePlay: true,
pauseText: 'Pause The Slide Show',
  playText: 'Playing The Slide Show'
  */
  });
});
</script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gallery.js"></script>
<noscript>
  <style>
  .es-carousel ul{
 display:block;
 }
 </style>
</noscript>
<script id="img-wrapper-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">   
 <div class="rg-image-wrapper">
   {{if itemsCount > 1}}
<div class="rg-image-nav">
 <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>
  <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>
  </div>
{{/if}}
 <div class="rg-image"></div>
 <div class="rg-loading"></div>
 <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">
 <div class="rg-caption" style="display:none;">
<p></p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Chat.js"></script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-43258818-1', 'gasssecurity.com');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: It has to do with the browser itself.  So, I have no clue on how to fix it.  I can only give you that bit of information (Which you probably already knew. Not sure.)

Comment: @XeroElixir is it has something to do with CSS cache?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! :-) Please post the HTML of the website; at-least the <head>...</head>.

Comment: @JackWilliams,ive edit my question with my html. As for your information, I am new to this programming world, I hope that you can help me. thank you!

Comment: Okay, the linking of the CSS seems fine. You could try calling your scripts such as jquery near to the </body> at alleviate some of the http requests coming from the head of the document. Give that a go. And re-ordering the CSS files so that the .css files for the page layout is first and the css for sliders ect. come afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of a blue to light blue gradient and the code needed to work in all browsers:

```
background: rgb(184, 225, 252);

/* Old browsers */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1) 10%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1) 25%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1) 37%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1) 51%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1) 83%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1) 100%);

/* FF3.6+ */

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1)), color-stop(37%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1)), color-stop(83%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1)));

/* Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1) 10%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1) 25%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1) 37%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1) 51%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1) 83%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1) 100%);

/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1) 10%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1) 25%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1) 37%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1) 51%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1) 83%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1) 100%);

/* Opera 11.10+ */

background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1) 10%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1) 25%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1) 37%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1) 51%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1) 83%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1) 100%);

/* IE10+ */

background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(184, 225, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(169, 210, 243, 1) 10%, rgba(144, 186, 228, 1) 25%, rgba(144, 188, 234, 1) 37%, rgba(144, 191, 240, 1) 50%, rgba(107, 168, 229, 1) 51%, rgba(162, 218, 245, 1) 83%, rgba(189, 243, 253, 1) 100%);

/* W3C */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=1);

/* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you styles are in the head of the page so they load before the rest of the assets do.

```
<html>
<title></title>
<styles here..../>
<body>
content ...
...
...
...
...
...
<script's here>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ive edit my question with part of my html,, am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes your code is acceptible but it is best practice to put all scripts at the end of the page before the closing body tag because they dont need to load imediatly. think of the browser loading top down. You would want the styles to load first then your content and then your scripts because people wont be interacting with your scripts before the page is loaded. The reason it is not displaying correctly in certain browsers is styling is differnt for most browsers and some things are supported in older browsers but not new and some old code is depricated in new browsers.